# Getting current visible item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with fullscreen RecyclerView to load images. The user can swipe left-right to view next item (achieved this by `LinearSnapHelper`) Over the image, it has Floating action bar whose action is to download the currently visible image.

Problem is when I click the FAB, instead of downloading the current image it downloads next item. Because `onBindViewHolder` gets executed in advance for the next and previous item. Problem doesn't occur when FAB is part of item layout but in this case Fab is part of Activity layout.

Adapter-

```
public class FullWallAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FullscreenViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> mWallKeys;
private OnFullSetupViewListener mOnFullSetupViewListener;

public FullWallAdapter(ArrayList<String> wallKeys, OnFullSetupViewListener listener) {
    this.mWallKeys = wallKeys;
    this.mOnFullSetupViewListener = listener;
}

@Override
public FullscreenViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fullscreen_wallpaper_preview, parent, false);
    return new FullscreenViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FullscreenViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ValueEventListener wallListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            ImageModel image = dataSnapshot.getValue(ImageModel.class);
            mOnFullSetupViewListener.onSetupView(holder, image, holder.getAdapterPosition(), dataSnapshot.getKey());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("WallAdapter", "Error occurred: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };
    DatabaseReference ref = FireUtils.getWallpapersRef().child(mWallKeys.get(position));
    ref.addValueEventListener(wallListener);
    holder.mWallRef = ref;
    holder.mWallListener = wallListener;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mWallKeys.size();
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(FullscreenViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    if (holder.mWallListener != null)
        holder.mWallRef.removeEventListener(holder.mWallListener);
}

public interface OnFullSetupViewListener {
    void onSetupView(FullscreenViewHolder holder, ImageModel image, int position, String wallKey);
}
}
```

In activity-

```
FullWallAdapter adapter = new FullWallAdapter(wallKeys, new FullWallAdapter.OnFullSetupViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSetupView(final FullscreenViewHolder holder, final ImageModel image,
                                int position, final String wallKey) {
            holder.setImageView(image);

            downloadFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    incrementDownload(wallKey, image);
                    String params;
                    params = wallpaper.getPhotoJson();
                    fetchSave(params);

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only think of the solution as follows.
Trigger onClickListener every time the user scrolls.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            currentPosition = llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            downloadFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                ...
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: perfect Thanks!

Comment: And the hell is llm variable ? I see no definition ?

Comment: I assume `llm` is linear layout manager

Comment: @MathematicsBeginner Yes it is instance of LinearLayoutManager.